# discord.js - cast or convert GuildChannel to TextChannel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to retrieve a certain channel from an ID or mention. Whenever I retrieve the channel from the guild's list of channels, it is in the form of a `GuildChannel`, which cannot directly have messages sent to using .send(message). I've looked briefly through the docs for a way to convert from `Guild Channel` to one of TextChannel | DMChannel | NewsChannel but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to do this based off of a message that was sent then you should be able to use.

```
message.guild.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID").send("message");
```

When accessing a channel from cache, it is good to know that the type of channel you receive is a GuildChannel, as the library doesn't know what sort of channel you are retrieving. TextChannel, VoiceChannel, and NewsChannel all inherit from GuildChannel, so intellisense and Typescript will not recognize channel type specific methods and properties such as `send()`. If you are indeed retrieving a TextChannel, then the send method will actually be available.

If you are using Typescript and are getting the error `Property 'send' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel'.ts(2339)`. You can fix this by first checking the type of the channel and making sure that it is a text channel.

Source: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3622#issuecomment-565550605

Comment: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel'.ts(2339). The whole issue is that that cache returns a GuildChannel object instead of the normal (TextChannel | DMChannel | NewsChannel) which all have .send() defined.

SO I need to convert that GuildChannel to a regular channel

Comment: This sounds like a Typescript issue. I'm not familiar with Typescript. While it is true that "GuildChannel" doesn't have the send method when it comes to Typechecking, The method is actually there and will work. I've had this discussion with moderators from the Discord.js community, and it's because you are fetching a channel from the cache. There is no way for it to know if the channel is a text channel or a voice channel so it gives you a GuildChannel object. Under the hood though you can still send messages to it.

Comment: If you want to do things the Typescript way, you can check out this https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3622#issuecomment-565550605

Comment: Ok thanks, it's kind of gross that it doesn't exist in TS or even in the docs here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildChannel

Comment: I agree. I was struggling with a similar issue. the send method wasn't populating from intellisense due to this same thing. I ended up reaching out to the mods in the Discord.js community and that's when they told me this.I'm going to update my answer to give a bit more information about this.